# Optimise query selecting latest result from result list for each client

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, sql-server-2016, join, cte

I'm hoping to time optimise a currently working query for a large production healthcare database. My current code takes about ~30 seconds to run. MSSQL 2016.

Firstly, I'm selecting just patients from a specific hospital inpatient medical team and storing that in cte `ActiveVisits`. Then, I'm grabbing the `GUID` for specific results stored in cte `ResultItems` which I'll later fetch so I don't need to  use slow string comparison.

Finally, for each patient in cte `ActiveVisits`, I want to get just their latest blood test result for each result item in cte `ResultItems`. Therefore, for ~20 patients, I'd have about ~180 results (thus 180 rows). Note that `CV3BasicObservation` table has over 300 million rows.

```
WITH ActiveVisits AS (
   SELECT
      av.GUID as 'VisitGUID',
      av.ChartGUID as 'ChartGUID'
   FROM CV3ActiveVisitList av
   WHERE av.ServiceDescription = 'Specific Medical Team'
), ResultItems AS (
   SELECT rc.GUID
   FROM CV3ResultCatalogItem rc
   WHERE rc.ItemName IN (
      'Sodium Level',
      'Potassium Level',
      'Magnesium Level',
      'Calcium Level',
      'Creatinine - Serum',
      'Albumin Level',
      'Haemoglobin',
      'White Cell Count',
      'C-Reactive Protein'
   )
)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties
   av.*,
   o.ItemName AS 'ResultName',
   o.Entered AS 'ResultDate',
   o.Value AS 'ResultValue'
FROM CV3BasicObservation o
   INNER JOIN ActiveVisits av ON av.ChartGUID = o.ChartGUID
   INNER JOIN ResultItems ri ON ri.GUID = o.ResultItemGUID
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY av.VisitGUID, o.ResultItemGUID ORDER BY o.Entered DESC)
```

`CV3BasicObservation` only non-clustered index (also PK) is `GUID` which I am not using. Clustered indexes are `ChartGUID` and `ClientGUID`

Comment: [How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/how-to-get-answers-to-sql-server-performance-questions/)

Comment: Sadly, I do not have `SHOWPLAN` permissions, but I'll get together an example dataset

Comment: Can you ask for `SHOWPLAN` permissions (they're rather benign) or ask someone who has them to get the actual execution plan for you? That will provide the information needed to help troubleshoot a performance problem. Without it, it's like telling a mechanic your car has engine problems without letting them look under the hood.

Comment: Agreed - I fired off an email an hour ago. I'll review this question once I have that information.

Comment: [Don't use this `TOP 1` with ties approach](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/317999/3690) - if you are going to use `ROW_NUMBER` then just filter on where that equals `1`. If you only want 180 rows out of a table with 300 million rows you would likely be much better off just doing 180 seeks with `TOP 1` though anyway - but you need a suitable index for that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Been nearly a week now with no additional information added to the Q - is it abandoned?

Comment: I have been unable to get SHOWPLAN permissions so I'm unable to provide more specific information. This, yes.